# R: regex for extracting non-numeric entries from a character vector of numbers

Tags: r, regex, subset, data-extraction, grepl

I have a data.frame in which one column of numeric data is read by readr as character, at least in part because some of the values are "N/A". I don't know if the values actually include quotation marks.

I am trying to extract all the values in that column that contain things other than pure numbers, i.e. which contain a any character which not a number, 1-9. My purpose is to learn how many of these there are and to see if there are any formats besides the "N/A", in preparation for replacing them with something else and then converting the vector to numeric.

While I am confident that there are smarter ways to do this, I am trying to extract those values with a logical vector created from a regex applied to to the vector using R's grepl command.

```
A2 <- 1:10
A3 <- sample(1000:9999, 10)

dat_df <- data.frame(A2, A3)
str(dat_df)
dat_df$A3[1:3]<- c("N/A", "", "banana")
```

`dat_df` is a simplified data set, provided for reproducibility.

Here is an example

```
dat_df$A3[grepl(as.character(\<\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*>\), x = dat_df$A3)]
```

This particular one gives the error

```
Error: unexpected '<' in dat_df"$A3[grepl(as.character(\<"
```

I have tried a lot of varients of this. These include:
Wrapping the initial data in `( )` (in case it was a precedence problem).
Defining the regex as a character string using `as.character` as the help file recommends, or with quotation marks.
Wrapping the central portion of the regex with `^` and `$` instead of  `\<` and `>\`
Doubling all the "`\`"s

In every case I get some variant of the syntax error shown above, varying with the version.

```
Error: unexpected (and then)
```

- '^' if it starts with a '^'
- '\' if it starts with a '\'
- '<' if it starts with a '<'
- '\d' if it is wrapped in quotation marks instead of using
  as.character

I can not make heads or tails out of this pattern of errors.

Any help gratefully received and acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `as.character(\<\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*>\)` is incorrect and doesn't work. For example, `as.character(A)` doesn't give you "A" but gives an error. You should enclose the pattern with quotes.

Secondly, in R regex you need to use double backslash to escape. So `\\` instead of `\`.

If you only have integer data you can use `grep` with `invert = TRUE` and `value = TRUE` to get the values which are not numbers.

```
grep('^\\d+$', dat_df$A3, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "N/A"    ""       "banana"
```

To change these values to `NA` and turn them to numeric you may do -

```
dat_df$A3[grep('^\\d+$', dat_df$A3, invert = TRUE)] <- NA
dat_df$A3 <- as.numeric(dat_df$A3)
dat_df

#   A2   A3
#1   1   NA
#2   2   NA
#3   3   NA
#4   4 7475
#5   5 1162
#6   6 9828
#7   7 6359
#8   8 7823
#9   9 2544
#10 10 5287
```

You can also use `grepl` to do the same if you prefer that over `grep` but it doesn't have `value` and `invert` argument so might need to change few small things to make it work.